# NServicebus and Message Handler order

Tags: handler, message, nservicebus

I'm sorry I was unclear. In fact there are not any dependencies between the handlers, some of them just handle the same type of message. For instance in our system we handle invoices, very simplified this happens when an invoice arrives to the system: an "InvoiceArrived" message is sent to the nservicebus and two things should happen, information about the invoice should be sent to an external system and an email should be sent to the person who is to handle the invoice (different person depending on the information on the invoice). These two things has no dependency on each other but the export to the external system is very important whereas the email is not as important.

What happened was that the handler sending email was run first and it crached (due to bad configuration), it was retried five times but crached each time and neither email nor export to external system took place. Fixing the configuration was easy but it showed us a flaw in our design.

I reallize now that we have to rethink the design because specifying the order in which the handlers are run would not solve anything as the opposite situation is also not desirable, that it runs the exporting handler first and then craches in the emailing handler resulting in five retries and five successful exports (but no successful email). I guess we will have to send one message type for each handler...

Original message:

We are using NServiceBus to set up handlers for a number of events, each sending a unique message type to the bus (currently 6 but the number is growing). Some of these events (2 at the moment) have more than one handler and we want them to be executed in a specific order for each of the message types.

We have our own host and I know you can specify the order as:
    NServiceBus.Configure.With()
    ...
    .UnicastBus()
    .LoadMessageHandlers(First.Then().AndThen().AndThen() //etc)

Lets say we have message handlers H1_1, H1_2 (both handling messages of type 1, H1_1 to be executed before H1_2) correspondingly H2_1, H2_2 (handling messages of type 2) and H3 - H6 (the only ones to handle messages of type 3 - 6)

Of course we can manage this by specifying all handlers

```
.LoadMessageHandlers(First<H1_1>.Then<H1_1>().Then<H2_1>() //etc)
```

but this means that every time we add a new handler we have to add to this configuration,

is it possible to write

```
.LoadMessageHandlers(First<H1_1>.Then<H2_1>()) //and all the other handlers are run there after?
```

That would of course be better but still, H1_1 and H2_1 has nothing with each other to do and will not be run on the same message any way. Is there no way to specify per message type, i.e. for type 1 `First<H1_1>.Then<H1_2>()` and for type 2 `First<H2_1>.Then<H2_2>()` and for all other types no specification is necessary since there is only one handler?

Thank you very much in advance - any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The fact that you have that many dependencies between your handlers might be a sign that your design needs some adjustment. Can you give us some details on what those handlers are doing and why the order in which they execute matters?

Comment: It also sounds like you may benefit from moving each set of message types to different endpoints.  This would allow you order them differently, but I agree with Andreas, it sounds like we need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 3.0 we're going to support multiple implementations of ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering for exactly these reasons.